# Error Using a string which refers to a Color to set a textColor

Tags: android, eclipse, android-xml

I had this 'colors.xml' file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<!-- Absolute colors -->
<color name="red">#FF0000</color>

<!-- Application colors -->
<string name="error_message_color">@color/red</string>

</resources>
```

And I used the Application Color to set a TextView text color in this way:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/error_message_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/error_message_label"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@string/error_message_color" 
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

But now, with Eclipse ADT 23.0.2.1259578 the part

```
<string name="error_message_color">@color/red</string>
```

give this error: *Unexpected resource reference type; Expected value of @string/*

And I couln't compile.

Why this? Someone know how can I solve?

PS: I know that if I'll use @color/red in textColor attribute the problem will be solved, but I would keep the "application color" coding style...

Thanks

Comment: Are you **serious**? You pretend to put a **string** where a **color** should be? Why do you **mix** colors and strings?

Comment: Just use the `@color/red` directly, no need to use it from a string resource.

Comment: please replace android:textColor="@string/error_message_color" with android:textColor="@color/red" or directly give hex color code android:textColor="#FF0000"

Comment: @Frank N. Stein , I'm just started studing about Android, and that was an example in a book... And that code worked... The problem happen with this version of ADT. I know that if I use @color/red I could solve the problem, but the question wasn't that! I just wanna understand why know that kind of coding style give an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to have aliases for your colors try referencing a color from a color and use that instead.

```
 <!-- Absolute colors -->
<color name="red">#FF0000</color>

<!-- Application colors -->
<color name="error_message_color">@color/red</color>

...

android:textColor="@color/error_message_color"
```

Comment: Maybe I explained bad the question (sorry for my english). The coding style used in my xml files was found in a book about Android and it worked fine 'till that version of the ADT. I know the way suggested to avoid the compiling error, but I would know if this problem would be present because it's better using directly a color and it's perhaps deprecated the way shown in that example or if it's a ADT issue.